# Yaml Variable not working for dockerfile using variables

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

So I have the following variable comdition defined in my YAML

```
  ${{ if endsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main' ) }}: 
    dFile: 'Dockerfile'
  ${{ if endsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'development' ) }}: 
    dFile: 'Development.Dockerfile'
```

I then use this in a build image task like this:

```
      - task: Docker@0
        displayName: 'Build an image'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'Azure Registry'
          azureContainerRegistry: 'redacted'
          dockerFile: $[variables.dFile]
          imageName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)-$(build.sourceBranch):$(Build.BuildNumber)'
          includeLatestTag: true
```

But for some reason this is the output I get:

```
##[error]Unhandled: No Docker file matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/$[variables.dockerFile]  was found.
```

I also tried `'$(dFile)'` and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defines the variables as name-value pair.

Here is what your variables block would look like:

```
variables:
  - ${{ if endsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main' ) }}:
      - name: dFile
        value: 'Dockerfile'

  - ${{ if endsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'development' ) }}:    
      - name: dFile
        value: 'Development.Dockerfile'
```